# Will OID change amoung same kind of devices

Tags: snmp

I'm using SNMP to enquire the status of a certain make of printer.
For example,the status of make1 printer has an OID '1',
I want to know if this OID will, for example, in a make2 printer, remain the same as make1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is probably better suited to SuperUser than Stack Overflow. However, the answer is "it depends". There are many IETF standard MIBs, which *usually* vendors endeavor to implement if they existed the vendor was aware of them at the time the device's agent was implemented. In such cases, these will be the same from one make to the next if both vendors implement those standard MIBs. Vendors may also have their own enterprise-specific MIBs that will not be implemented in different vendors' devices.

There is an IETF standard Printer MIB, that you will likely find implemented in just about any SNMP-capable printer on the market, but I assume printers were just being used as an example for the sake of your question.